# How to extract composeBom dependencies code to external files in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-jetpack-compose

I have an external file.

```
def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.12.00')
```

But this caused an error, it seems that in the external file there is no `platform()`

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method platform() for arguments [androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.12.00] on object of type org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something different:

Define:

```
buildscript {
   ext {
        composeBom = 'androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.12.00'

   }
}
```

Then in the `dependencies` block

```
dependencies {

    implementation (platform(composeBom))
    //..
}
```

Comment: This is actually not what I expected, it doesn't pull the code out of the app/build file.

Comment: @FreedomFoolt I am not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: I extract the code related to `composeBom` from the `build` file to the `a` file, and then import these codes from the `a` file to the `build` file.